# Reuse View with different ViewModel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm learning how to make a WPF application by making a tool to help me with Dungeons & Dragons.
Basically it's a database of Items, where I can also generate a list of loot by "rolling" on a "Treasure Table" which gives me "Item Tables" to in turn roll on.

I'm done making both the Item database viewer as well as a window where you can select an Item table, see its contents in a datagrid and add, edit, and delete Item Tables.

I now need to make the same for Treasure Tables. It needs to be so similar to the Item Table editor, that I wonder If I can't just reuse it, feeding a TreasureTableVM in instead of an ItemTableVM. Depending on which VM is set as the Window's DataContext, the view would do things slightly different, including showing different some columns in the datagrid.

The TreasureTableVM and ItemTableVM have the same methods and properties, although with slightly different implementation. Also a couple properties have different types (currentTable is TreasureTable in TreasureTableVM, ItemTable in ItemTableVM. CurrentRow is TreasureTableRow in one, ItemTableRow in the other. TableList is ObservableCollection in one, ObsevableCollection in the other)

How would I go about it?

Comment: One possibility is to have one viewmodel type and inject different behaviour via the ctor. Treasure is passed one action and items a different one. If the view is to bind to your two types they need the same properties and commands. Your observablecollection could be of object. But are these two things really that different?

Comment: The simplest would be to create a `UserControl` e.g., `TreasureControl` which is composed of all the elements you wish to reuse. If you mean to use a single control for multiple view models, then create a parent view model that exposes the current view model via a property e.g., `CurrentTreasureModel` and bind it to `TreasureControl.DataContext`. You'd then set `CurrentTreasureModel` e.g. to `TreasureTableVM`.

Comment: Create an interface e.g. `ITreassureViewModel` which defines all shared properties and methods. This interface will also be the type of the `CurrentTreasureModel` property. Let both your view models implement this interface. It must be clear that in order to share the view, the bound properties must be named equally in each view model and be of the same type. It's not possible to name a property `TreasureTableRow` in one viewmodel and `ItemTableRow` in the other.

Comment: If you need more help, you should post both view models and their dependencies e.g. the object type in the collections.

Comment: The UserControl solution sounded very reasonable for my situation, but I already had the interface solution halfway done and decided to figure out how to get to work thanks to @BionicCode 's suggestion. 
It works! But now I have a table with some empty columns since TreasureTable doesn't have all the same ones as ItemTable. I'm thinking I'll collapse them based on a binding to an enum in the ViewModels, but it won't fix the "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: property not found on 'object'" error that the output tells me about.
Is there a way to disable a binding?

Comment: Your `DataGrid` is not auto-generated? Can you please post the controls you want to reuse and the context, how you use it, data context, parent control etc.It's difficult to give you a good solution without knowing what and how you've implemented it. As I said before, both view models should have the same properties. Whatever you are displaying in the `DataGrid` must have the same properties. If the data items  have the same properties, then the bindings will resolve. Properties that are not initialized i.e. `null`, will result in empty columns. Please post details!

Comment: I avoided autogenerating, because I wanted to set some column properties and converters, but on your suggestion I went on a deep dive and found out howto set those things programmatically (because nothing else would work).

In an autoGeneratingColumn Event I create a style and set it to all non null columns, and for certain properties I cancel it, set the converter, width, and/or header name, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same table and just add a new field in your datacontext, named "type" and the value is "treasure" or "item".
Then on your VM just filter the data by type.